# Adding more than 3 fingerprints in Galaxy S5 by swiping different fingers when adding a new fingerprint

Tags: security, samsung-galaxy-s-5

On the Samsung Galaxy S5 one can [bypass the 3 fingerprint limit by swiping different fingers when adding a new fingerprint](http://youtu.be/jUw_luFsIIg). Can this cause any security issue?

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.